# Constrain pin to top layout guide not enabled

Tags: ios, uistoryboard

I am trying to pin a UILabel to the top layout guide but the option does not seems to be enabled.

All my other views on the same controller has such option. Anyone knows what might be the cause?

Comment: Show your viewcontroller hierarchy in screenshot

Comment: I got it resolved, please see my answer. Do you know if this behaviour is intended? If so, why?

Answer (score 0):

I got it resolved by shifting the hierarchy down such that it is not the top element under the view on the storyboard scene.

Weird behaviour, anyone knows what the intention behind this?